# Can I create a List<T> of enumerated values?

Tags: .net, generics, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm writing WinForms application and I want to create an enumerable type. If I write

```
enum Op { plus, minus, mul, div };
```

I can't create `List<Op> ops;` — it causes an error

> "Op" is not a valid generic argument

*(`System::Collections::Generic::List` is an analog of `std::vector`)*

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but I'm guessing it may be the scope of the declaration? `List<Op> ops` should work perfectly. There is no problem using an enum as the generic type.

Comment: @CodyGray, I tried to put `enum Op { plus, minus, mul, div };` inside `class MyForm`, inside `namespace MyApp` or in global scope, it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this declaring

```
public enum class Op { plus, minus, mul, div };
```

outside `class MyForm`

Then I can use it as

```
List<Op> ops;
ops.Add(Op::plus);
```

Please write if it exist any better solution.

Comment: It is not, `enum class` was adopted in C++11 and thus still defines an unmanaged type.  Making it managed now requires explicitly using the accessibility specifier.  Use `public` or `private`.  The OP also needs to read up on *stack semantics*, makes little sense to use it on the List type since it is not disposable.

Comment: @Hans you're right, I should have included `public` in my comment above. My point was to say there's no "better solution" than a managed enum, as OP asks. But using stack semantics for non disposable types lets you use somewhat simpler syntax (no ugly `^` and `.` instead of `->`). I don't think it's really harmful *as long as you know what you're doing*. I can think of one downside though: it can easily hide usage of disposable types if you use it too much.